# Mean value formula integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: B(0,R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then I was wondering whether

$$\frac{1}{\text{area}(\partial B(0,r))} \int_{\partial B(0,r)} (f(x)-f(0)) dS(x) \rightarrow_{r \rightarrow 0} 0.$$

for $B(0,r) \subset B(0,R).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

> We want to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$
>   such that if $0 < r < \delta$ we have $$\frac{1}{\text{area}(\partial
>  B(0,r))} \Big|\int_{\partial B(0,r)} (f(x)-f(0))\,dS(x)\Big| \le \epsilon.$$

So let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. 
By assumption $f$ is continuous, hence there is $\delta$ such that if $x \in B(0,\delta)$ then $$|f(x) - f(0)| \le \epsilon.$$ Let $r < \delta$, then we have $$\frac{1}{\text{area}(\partial B(0,r))} \Big|\int_{\partial B(0,r)} (f(x)-f(0))\,dS(x)\Big| \le \frac{1}{\text{area}(\partial B(0,r))} \int_{\partial B(0,r)} |f(x)-f(0)|\,dS(x) \le \epsilon \cdot 1.$$
This concludes the proof.